# select two counts from a table with 1 pass using SQL?

Tags: sql

Say if we do such query:

```
select
  (select count(*) as count_ca from employees where state = 'CA'),
  (select count(*) as count_all from employees);
```

is it true that the SQL statement will need to go through the table twice, even when the table has 20 million rows?  If we write a program we can keep 2 counts and just make 1 pass through the table records. Does the SQL statement do 2 passes and is it possible to make it 1 pass?

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*), sum(case when state = 'CA' then 1 else 0 end)
from employees;
```